# I need grub to support BIOS and UEFI at the same time?

Tags: bios, grub, uefi, refind

The Arch Linux ISO can be booted both in BIOS and EUFI mode, but how can we install an Arch Linux that both support UEFI and BIOS booting? And what's the partition layout, I used this layout but it didn't work:

```
/dev/sda1   ----    EFI System---- vfat32  
/dev/sda2   ----    BIOS      ---- vfat32
/dev/sda3   ----    /         ---- ext4
/dev/sda4   ----    /home     ---- ext4
/dev/sda5   ----    swap      ----
```

and mounted it like this:

```
/dev/sda1   ----    /boot/EFI ---- vfat32
/dev/sda2   ----    /boot     ---- vfat32
/dev/sda3   ----    /         ---- ext4
/dev/sda4   ----    /home     ---- ext4
/dev/sda5   ----    swap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "BIOS" partition **is not /boot**. In fact, it doesn't have a filesystem at all, and should not be mounted anywhere – it contains just the raw GRUB bootloader code (its "stage 2" or "core image").

The "EFI" partition should be mounted at `/boot/efi`, lowercase. (Don't confuse the mountpoint with the *subdirectory* "EFI" that exists within this partition. It's normal to have /boot/efi/EFI as a subdirectory.)

(The EFI partition may also be just `/boot`, but for GRUB it's fine to use /boot/efi.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your suggestion and see if it works.